# Honda Accord 2006 back right door lock got stuck

Tags: honda, locks, door

The back right door of my Honda Accord got stuck and will not open. The door is stuck in locked and will not unlock. How can I fix this?

Comment: Again as with your other question, we really need more information to help you out. Does it seem to be an electrical issue or a mechanical issue? Can you hear the locking mechanism trying to work when you click the button? All the other doors work without issue? Is there a mechanical button on the door itself which is not working? Anything else you can tell us?

Comment: It was working all of a sudden and it just stopped. Only that door doesn't work everything else works. You can still hear the lock trying to get unlocked if I press the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question: Did someone turn on the child safety latch and you've only tried to open the door from the inside? Outside chance, but I thought I'd mention it. Obviously, if the door is unlocked you can still unlatch it from the outside.

It could be either one of two things: the rod which goes from the lock solenoid to the locking mechanism is broke (or detached); or, the rod which goes from the handle to the latching mechanism is broke (or detached). I would think it probably has to do with the lock rather than the latch.

You can try to see if while someone is hitting the unlock switch if you pull on the door handle it may decide to work. If that doesn't work, your only alternative is to take the inside door panel off of the door. I know that would be a pain if it is closed, but it is about your only alternative. You should be able to remove the bottom of the back seat to gain you more access room.

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually unlock the door by pulling the pole up or moving the lock switch over?
I know this is not an answer but without being there I need more information.

Comment: No it cant be pulled up, it is stuck.

Comment: sometimes when I lock my door and I accidentally shut the seat belt in there it gets stuck.  I have to try and push the door closed with my body while someone else pulls the lever up, or pull the seat belt out the releave the pressure on the latching mechanism so it can unlock etc.

Comment: Try to push on the door and see if someone else can pull the lever/ bar up.    P.S. is the door shut all the way? is it propped open slightly?  even if it looks closed all the way it would be wedged.